# Mock a custom service with jest and enzyme for a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple component that loads up some users from an api call, which I have abstracted in a service. Here is the Component:

```
export const Dashboard: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUser[]>([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const userService: UserService = UserService.get();

    useEffect(() => {
        userService.getUsers()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                setIsLoading(false)
                setUsers(data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Could not load users: ", error);
                setIsLoading(false)
                setUsers([]);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        isLoading
            ?
            <div data-testid="loading">
                <h4>Loading...</h4>
            </div>
            :
            <div data-testid="users">
                <UserList users={users}/>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

And my service looks like this:

```
export class UserService {
    private static INSTANCE = new UserService();

    private constructor() {}

    public static get(): UserService {
        return UserService.INSTANCE;
    }

    public async getUsers(): Promise<IUser[]> {
        const response = await axios.get("api/users");
        return response.data as IUsers[];
    }
}
```

The reason I have extracted it in a .ts file is that I am planing to be reusing this service in another component and also add here other api calls.

So now I want to write a simple test for my Dashboard component, where I mock the UserService to return a promise and then test that my `data-testid=users` is rendered.

Here is my test:

```
configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
describe("User dashboard component", () => {

    let userService: UserService;

    const users = [
        {
            id: "0c8593e8-8fa6-4d40-b555-5ef812477c70",
            name: "John",
            age: 25
        }
    ];

    beforeAll(() => {
        userService = UserService.get();
    });

    test("renders component", () => {
        userService.getUsers = () => {
            return Promise.resolve(users);
        };
        
        const dashboard = shallow(<Dashboard />);
        expect(dashboard.find(<Dashboard />)).toBeTruthy();

        expect(dashboard.find('[data-testid="users"]').length).toEqual(1);
        expect(toJson(dashboard)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    test("loading", () => {
        const dashboard = shallow(<Dashboard />);
        expect(dashboard.find('[data-testid="loading"]').length).toEqual(1);
        expect(toJson(dashboard)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

I don't want to mock the `useState` hook, but apparently my part where I resolve a Promise with users does nothing.

How do I achieve that? what is the best practice here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shallow` doesn't support `useEffect`](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086) at this moment, `mount` should be used instead.

The component is rendered asynchronously and the test should be asynchronous too. Mocking methods by assignment is a bad practice because they cannot be restored, this results in test cross-contamination. A promise that makes it asynchronous should be exposed for chaining. In case of a spy it can be retrieved via Jest spy API.

It should be:

```
jest.spyOn(userService, 'getUsers').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(users));

const dashboard = mount(<Dashboard />);
expect(userService.getUsers).toBeCalledTimes(1);
await act(async () => {
  await userService.getUsers.mock.results[0].value;
});
...
```

Spies should be restored and cleared between tests in order for tests to not affect each other.

Comment: Thanks for the post! I am new to Jest and react hooks, but what I tried did not work. `jest.spyOn(userService, 'getUsers', () => Promise.resolve(users));` produces an error: `Error: Property getUsers does not have access type () => Promise.resolve(users)`

Also the `await userService.getUsers.mock.results[0].value;` gets a syntax error.

Comment: Fixed it. What syntax error? `await` is allowed only inside `async` function. It should be asynchronous test with `async` function. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#asyncawait

Comment: The error with await is `The 'await' operator can only be used in an 'async' function`. Ah ok thanks for the link! I get it now. But another thing, I tried your correction with the mockImplementation and the expectation is not met - the number of calls is 0. Maybe there is something I am doing wrong with my Service?

Comment: The error refers to the function where `await` is used, i.e. test function. See the remark regarding `shallow`. It should be `mount`. I see it as the only reason for it to not be called, because UserService is a singleton, so userService.getUsers in the test is the same as the one that's used in the component.

Comment: You are right, I did change to `mount` but then must have made an undo. I getting another error related to trying to update React state and not wrapping into act(). Is this also something to do with the `async` nature?

Comment: Yes, should be something like https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching . Enzyme renderer is synchronous, `act` part isn't covered by it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ditched enzyme completely and I am going to be using `render` and `react-test-renderer` instead. I think the enzyme is for my case an overkill.

Comment: You're welcome. FWIW, React Testing Library is more suitable for testing functional components than Enzyme.